# Removing ''\" from output

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to remove backslash from my output, `replacingOccurrences` is not working. I want to make dictionary of `[String:String]` type, where second string contains an array and that array contains string inside it i.e `deviceID`.

```
            let deviceIdArray = [membrs.deviceID!]
            //  str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "") this is not working
            var deviceIdDict: [String:String] = [:]
            deviceIdDict = ["userData": "\(deviceIdArray)"]
            print("my dictionary: \(deviceIdDict)")
```

OUTPUT:

```
my dictionary: ["userData": "[\"CEA2CE6B-EE43-43B6-A04D-5D11BD65A762\"]"]
```

Comment: that is a designated escape character which appears on the console only when you print out the value – there is nothing to get rid of.

Comment: The backslash is not technically there, it is escaping the second set of double quotes in the string. if you assign this string to a label for example you wouldn't see the backslash

Comment: You may try to set the text to a label or textview, to get to see the difference between what is being printed, and what the actual text is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `debugDescription`

```
let dictString = deviceIdDict.debugDescription
    print(dictString)
```

It would print

```
["some": "more"]
```

You can try `dump`

```
print("my dictionary: ")
dump(deviceIdDict)
```

It'll be printed like this:

```
▿ 1 key/value pair
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "some"
    - value: "more"
```